# About inequalities (general)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I wonder if there is a sharper inequality than Hölder's inequality. I mean, we have
$$\int_A |fg|d\mu \leq \left( \int_A |f|^p d\mu \right)^{1/p} \left( \int_A |g|^q d\mu \right)^{1/q}$$
for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $fg\in L^1(A, \mu)$.
But, how accurate is this inequality? Are there others that might be better? Is there any book about inequalities and how optimal they are?
Thank you very very much!!

Comment: It is true, hence accurate, and sharp in the sense that you can find $f,g$ for which it is true.

Comment: I updated my comment, which should address part of your question.

Comment: But how big is the difference between the RHS and the LFH? maybe there are improvements? modifications of Hölder or other stuff.

Comment: It is a simple bound that is sharp for some $f,g$. Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but, for those f,g it might be an even sharper one. I mean for example, one has: $||a| - |b|| < |a+b|$ but a sharper inequality would be $||a| - |b|| < |a-b|$. I mean this but with Hölder's inequality

Comment: Have you seen [this paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article1172.html)?

Comment: No, but that's exactly what I meant, thank you very much! :) It might help, anyway it seems to be the sharpest one obtained by the moment. :) Thanks!

Comment: Take f=1 and g=1.

Answer (score 1):

The paper "Strengthened Cauchy-Schwarz and Hölder Inequalities" by J. M. Aldaz contains some sharpenings which may interest you.

It can be downloaded [from the Journal of Inequalities in Pure and Applied Mathematics webpage](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/article1172.html).

Comment: (Just turning my comment into an answer so the question doesn't remain "unanswered".)